# Can't get innerHTML from newly opened window

Tags: javascript, html

I've read many questions about this issue here at StackOverflow, but nothing works. I'm trying to open a new HTML file from a HTML file and manipulate the elements. Here is a bit of HTML-code for newfile.html:

```
<main>  
  <h1 id="myJob"></h1>
</main>
```

And here is a code from the js-file:

```
newWindow = window.open("newfile.html", "Some title", "width=700, height=2500");

newWindow.onload = function () {
  newWindow.document.getElementById("myJob").innerHTML ="hello";
};
```

The window is opening, but nothing happens with the element.

the full newfile.html looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css"
            href = "css/theCss.css">
            <script src="myScript.js"></script> 
   </head>
        <body>
            <main>  
                <h1 id="myJob"></h1>
            </main>
        </body>
</html>
```

Hank

Comment: What does _"nothing happens with the element"_ mean? can you alert the value? Do you get an error? try to be more informative.

Comment: I try your code.evething works fine.

Comment: if i put an alert before, in and after the function, only the first and last alert is called. Seems like the function isn't called for me.

Comment: innerText doesn't work :/

Comment: I think there must be something wrong in newfile.html can you put all html there is in newfile.html? because I cannot reproduce your problem

Comment: @ShirinAbdolahi I'm viewving the file in the original post now.

Comment: This code appears to work in Chome but not IE - which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior could be used for code injection. I don't think this is supported by any serious browser. It would be an immense exploit.

Comment: Things like this are deemed safe if both files are served from the same domain, which in this case they appear to be.